# cant progress with php 5 integer passing from a page

Tags: php

is_int in php 5 doesn't recognize a GET integer when it's passed to it

```
$blog_ident=$_GET['blog_id'];

if (is_int($blog_ident)){

    $sql="SELECT * FROM blog WHERE blog_id='$blog_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    if (!$result) {
        die('Sorry there was a problem reading the blog.');
    }

    // If we get a result back
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
        @extract($row);
    }
} else {
    die ('Problem with the blog');
}
```

> http://mydomain/blog_edit.php?blog_id=1

This always ends in 'Problem with the blog'. I can't get it to recognize the 1 as an int and proceed to the database query

Comment: all parameters are passed as string. php does not know which data type you expect. You should stick with `filter_var` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: and btw - you should upgrade to a newer version (e.g. 7.3)

Comment: your code is wide open to **SQL injection attacks** - use parameterised statements, or tell your users in advance that their data has been breached - because it will be.

Answer (score 1):

Values in the `$_GET` and `$_POST` super globals are always strings. You may either cast it as an INT or use `is_numeric` to see if the value is a number.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the second line of code, more specifically `is_int(...)`. The docs page for [`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) states its functionality as the following:

> Find whether the type of a variable is integer

The problem here is that the type of `$blog_ident` is a `string` even though the value is a number, because the contents of `$_GET` is always of the type string. `is_int` only checks the type of the variable, not its content. If you continue to read on the [docs page for is_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) you'll find this part.

> To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as form input, which is always a string), you must use is_numeric().

If you replace `is_int($blog_ident)` line to the following you should ger the desired result:

```
if (is_numeric($blog_ident)){
```

Comment: `is_numeric` also recognizes float